# Inducing autocorrelation by fitting the wrong ARMA?

Tags: autocorrelation, arma, lags

I am trying to fit an ARMA(p,q) model to the mean equation of my return series. The problem is, that the acf and pacf are pretty not usable, i.e. it is hard to find a good model to take account of the acf and pacf pattern. I am aware of the alternative of using no model at all for the mean equation.

Nevertheless I have a certain problem. I do *not* want to discuss about my model selection or if it is sensible to fit such a model, but I have a certain problem. After fitting (a possibly wrong) ARMA model to my data, I have the feeling, that I kind of "induced" autocorrelation at high lag orders. So before, there were no autocorrelation and afterwards it seems, that at low lag order I could make the autocorrelation "vanish", but in higher lag orders it increased.

So I do not know that much about this topic. So first of all:
Is this possible to induce wrong autocorrelation? So autocorrelation which was not there before? How is this procedure called? Any good articles/books about it?

Comment: Off my memory, yes, this is possible. Definitely with differencing, not sure about PQ terms. Not that I can remember from where, or if I just like to make things up. Hopefully someone else can jump in with actual references.

Comment: @Affine the same holds for me! I am sure I heard about it, but I am not into the topic nor do I have good articles or books about it.